# Missing info.plist value a key NSExtensionPointIdentifier in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

[image]

When i uploaded to iTunesConnect i got this error message, i have tried to change deployment target 9.2 to iOS 8.2 in extension but no results

Comment: what are your deployment target in info.plist.

Comment: in main app is iOS 9.3 and in Extension app is iOS 8.2 @iOSBadBoy

Comment: set MinimumOSVersion to pList=8.2 and try it again

Comment: in extension info.plist or main app info.pilst @iOSBadBoy

Comment: Kindly in extension

Comment: May be help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2410/_index.html

Comment: Thank you so much...Problem Solved @iOSBadBoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121174/discussion-between-vivek-goswami-and-ios-badboy).

Comment: @VivekGoswami Can you please let me know what the issue and how did it got rectified ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app extension `info.plist` file set `MinimumOSVersion` value to `8.2` and try it again.

Here's the [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2410/_index.html)